# Create new Excel application using RDCOMClient

Tags: r, rdcomclient

I have the following code which uses the existing and open Excel application.
How to I force R to open a new Excel application and open the workbook in this new Excel station?

```
xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open("S:/x/z/y.xlsb")
xlApp[['Visible']] <- TRUE
```

Comment: You don't need Excel to read or write Excel files. `xlsx` is a zip package containing XML files. You can use packages like openxlsx or xlsx to open them

Comment: The spreadsheet are saved in binary formats (xlsb) and runs a open_workbook macro which is executed and then the workbook is closed. My problem is simply that I would need it to run in a seperate Excel application if possible.

Comment: Do you want to open a new excel workbook or you want to force R to open the same workbook?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the following approach :

```
library(RDCOMClient)

path1 <- "D:\\test1.xlsx"
path2 <- "D:\\test2.xlsx"

xlApp1 <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlWbk1 <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path1)
xlApp1[['Visible']] <- TRUE 

xlApp2 <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlWbk2 <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path2)
xlApp2[['Visible']] <- TRUE
```